# How to add google pay payment gateway with react?

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, django, payment-gateway, google-pay

Hello guys I am trying to integrate a payment gateway for my first e-commerce process build with react and Django as the backend. I tried with Razorpay but they halted onboarding new merchants. After watching some videos I found that we can add google pay also with react with the google pay react button. I found this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-pay/button-react
to integrate payment, but it didn't show up option, just the card option and when I tried with the card in response it didn't show a proper response. it gives a token not a transaction or id as Razorpay or other payments give. Please guide me if anybody integrates payment with this library.

Comment: Please check your link i think you accidently added to at the end of it. instead of separate word. So the link should be https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-pay/button-react and not https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-pay/button-reactto.

Comment: Yes sir, just changed the link.